# Extracting info from blocks inside text file

Tags: text-processing

I have a text file which has blocks like

```
dir1/dir2/dir3/name_run_number1:
line1_run_number1_part1
line2_run_number1_part2
line3_run_number1_part3...
```

Each block is separated with a blank line and there is the ":" in the "header" of each one while each block has a unique "number1" after "run_" suffix which is also present in the lines inside the block

What I want to do is for each block, extract the "number1" as shown in the first line and then for the lines below count from 1-20 and give a message if a "partX" line is missing. Any bash or python would be fine

Thanks

Comment: `bash` is a command line interpreter, it doesn't do anything but call and orchestrate commands. Some of them can be `sed`, `awk`, `python`, `perl`... So _"Any bash or python"_ makes little sense.

Comment: Give longer example of input file and also desire output, it is hard to understand what do you want to achieve from given description.

Answer (score 0):

Based on given example of input|output decision can be:

```
awk -F_ '
    /:/ {
        for (i=0;i<20;i++) {
            getline
            sub("chunk","",$7)
            while ( i != +$7 ) {
                print "for " $2 " and " $5"_"$6 " you are missing chunk " i
                i++
                if (i>20)
                    break
                }
            }
    }' text.file
```

Comment: This does not work as expected...for instance
`sed -n '/number1:/,+20 {/:/d;/part[0-9]*$/! s/.*/your_message/p}'`

returns just "your_message" but nothing in case a "part" is missing and exactly which one

Comment: @Just_Newbie Therefore I ask for example input and desired output.

Comment: Input example  
`Output/13TeV_modelA_1300_100/13TeV_modelA_1300_100_run_30756:
13TeV_modelA_1300_100_run_30756_chunk0  <br/>
13TeV_modelA_1300_100_run_30756_chunk1  <br/>
13TeV_modelA_1300_100_run_30756_chunk10  
13TeV_modelA_1300_100_run_30756_chunk11  
13TeV_modelA_1300_100_run_30756_chunk12  
13TeV_modelA_1300_100_run_30756_chunk13
13TeV_modelA_1300_100_run_30756_chunk14
13TeV_modelA_1300_100_run_30756_chunk15
13TeV_modelA_1300_100_run_30756_chunk16
13TeV_modelA_1300_100_run_30756_chunk17
13TeV_modelA_1300_100_run_30756_chunk18`

clearly in this, some "chunks" are missing

Comment: the output could be any kind of "report" ie like  

  
`for modelA and run_30756 you are missing chunk X`  <br/>

Comment: @Just_Newbie Have edited. Please check for real data.